# Gtk.MenuItem on "activate" signal doesn't work

Tags: gtk, signals, pygtk, menuitem

I don't know why **i can't activate a menuitem**. I tried to connect my function handler many ***signals: "activate", "activate-item", "notify::active", "selected"***. But no one has worked.

I'm **using Glade**, i attach you a shot of my menubar (i hate that, on unity window manager, the menubar is showed in the window bar: it should be inside the application window).

[image]

The code i use for the signal handler is very simple:

```
builder.get_object('menuitem3').connect('activate', self.useless_method)
builder.get_object('window1').show()
```

Here below the XML code from the Glade file:

```
  <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">_File</property>
        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem2">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Modifica</property>
        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem3">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Visualizza</property>
        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
```

***Why isn't this working ?!?***

Comment: would you show us some of the code where the object Gtk.Menu is created?

Comment: just added, i hope you can find something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your glade file. i hard coded it and it worked. A little note though, since 'menuitem3' is a toplevel Menu, why you want to connect a signal? And perhaps your connected function ?

edited (your code):

```
 def useless_method(menuitem): <<< edited, note below

     print 'I am %s' % str(menuitem) <<< note below


 builder = Gtk.Builder()
 builder.add_from_file('menuitem.glade')

 builder.get_object('menuitem3').connect('activate', useless_method)
 builder.get_object('window1').show_all()

 Gtk.main()
```

Argument in signal from 'Gtk.MenuItem" only takes 1 argument which is pointer data. You put three of them. There is no need for 'self' unless you creating a class. 
You can pass the 'args()' alone, but I chose menuitem3 to pinpoint that you passed an object of Gtk.Widget to be printed as a string. Python will still print it (if you look at the console) the memory address of which Gtk.MenuItem (#3) is resided.
And last, since the 'menuitem3' is a toplevel Menu, the mechanism for the first click is dropping a menu (since there is no menu, it looks like it doesn't do anything), the second click, it will emit signal 'activate' and that's your function will do something. So click two times and it will trigger.
Sorry for too much explanation.

Comment: Please try to use the glade version: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ly18mj6tg4e22jc/AAB4pbGVrV73CSZ0HQ1RYoDza

Comment: glade file is good. edited source code. keep working on it.good stuff

Comment: Ok thanks! i've forgotten to cut off "self" parameter, but i need it inside my software (it is a instance-class method). For "menuitem" if you try to print it, it will print the name of the right menuitem object (through Gtk.Buildable.get_name() ).

Now i know that "activate" signal works just for menuitem children. So I think that I will have to replace signle menuitems with buttons or something other.